# using puppeteer or puppeteer-core in cli script

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to write a node cli script that will run some tests on the forms of a website I'm working on. I want to use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/) but I'm a bit confused about the difference between the full version and puppeteer-core. What is the best choice if I want to run the tests from a cli script without opening the browser and only simulating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, **puppeteer-core** is for when you already have a browser and don't want to download a whole Chromium which the main **puppeteer** package does, automatically.

It is better to go with the full puppeteer since this way you will be getting the "batteries included, tested and are guaranteed to work" experience.

Official documentation offers [a detailed comparison](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteer-vs-puppeteer-core).

Comment: I've already chrome installed in my mac so for testing maybe it's a bit overkill to install another browser?

Comment: Some point for using plain puppeteer: puppeteer will install its own browser automatically, it will not pollute the system apps; each puppeteer version is tied to a specific browser version - hence it is more reliable to use that; you won't have to tinker with connecting to your browser; your tests will work on any other computer because the browser will be the same; it's only ~300 Mb.

Comment: I'm testing now zombiejs but I will try also puppeteer. I'm reading the documentations, I suppose that it's capable to fill and submit forms and get headers, cookies ecc right?Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, it is. Also have a look, maybe this will be of use: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer

Comment: Never used jest, it's another framework for testing?

Comment: Indeed it is one of the modern standards for front-end testing.